# Laravel - Has many relationship not working inside foreach loop

Tags: laravel, has-many

I have a HasMany relationship that works on the whole site. Just made a new controller and in this controller I have this inside a method:

```
  // find all galleries that need to be deleted...
    $galleries = DB::table('galleries')->where('curdeldate', '<', time())->get();

    foreach($galleries as $gallery)
    {            

        //get all the images associated with the gallery
        $photos = $gallery->photos;
```

this throws this message: `ErrorException Undefined property: stdClass::$photos` but I cannot figure out why...

I also included this:

```
use App\Gallery;
use App\Photo;
```

Comment: what do you get when you do `dd($galleries)`

Comment: actually that can'T work because you use DB facade... that's like getting raw data from table... it's not connected with anything... no relationships...

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
$galleries = Gallery::where('curdeldate', '<', time())->get();

foreach($galleries as $gallery)
{            
    $photos = $gallery->photos;

.............
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked.. coudl you please explain what the difference is? why the other one does not work?

Comment: When you use DB facade it's like you are using raw SQL...
`SELECT * FROM 'galleries'` and you get only data from that table... the photos are in the 'photos' table and you would have to use join photos to get the photos also...
You could make it work also with DB:: but  I find this approach much cleaner and since you already have the Eloquent models why not to use them.